# Regular apeirohedra?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

Have been toying with structures that I think are best describe as unbounded [regular polyhedra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polyhedron). More specifically I arrived at non-convex polyhedra that are unbounded in one direction:

[image]

Alternate view of segments:

[image]

My question: what is the proper terminology for these structures? Should I refer to these as regular [apeirohedra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apeirohedron)? Is there a classification for such structures? Can these be generalized to structures that are unbounded in more dimensions?